# How to create a usable list of inputted items

Tags: c#, wpf, database

My end goal is to create a program where the user stores data (such as a shopping list, DVD collection, etc...) and then can be viewed and sorted in many different ways. I am attempting to build this program in WPF, using C#.
My dilemma is I don't know what the best option is, or how to start. I've looked in databases (it would need to be a free one like Microsoft Sql Express), .CSV files, and so forth. What would be the best way to build my program, and can you point me in a direction to get started?
I'm not looking for code examples (yet, anyway) I just don't even know where to start or even how to phrase this question in a way to get relevant results.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first take a blank sheet of paper and write down what your program should be able to do. After that, think about what classes would be neccessary to support the given abilities. Are there any attributes which are common in all objects? Probably make a diagramm with the relations. After that you will see if it is neccessary to use SQL. For most programms, especially the tiny ones, I wouldn't use a database. I experienced, that using a simple XML-file or application-settings are usual more than enought and pretty easy to use.
Write a library for your objects and then think about, again best on paper, how the frontend should look like.